# Rally: Update Test Folder refrenced in Test Case

Tags: java, web-services, rally

I have the following Java code(below) to update my Test Case. I am wanting to update three fields on my Test Case. The three Fields are Project, Test Folder, and Notes. The code while it works only updates the Project and Notes fields. The Test Folder field remains unchanged. What changes would I need to make in order to have it update my Test Folder field?
Thanks

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.CreateRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.UpdateRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.CreateResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.UpdateResponse;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.CreateRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.DeleteRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.GetRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.QueryRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.UpdateRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.CreateResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.DeleteResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.GetResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.QueryResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.UpdateResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.Fetch;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.QueryFilter;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.Ref;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.Ref;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi;

public class TestCaseUpdate {

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {


            String host = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
            String username = "username@company.com";
            String password = "secret";
            String wsapiVersion = "v2.0";
            String projectRef = "/project/387xxxx.js";
            String tfRef = "/testfolder/198xxx.js";
                    //String tfRef = "/testfolders/198xxx.js";
            String applicationName = "RestExample_createTFandTC";



                    RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(
                     new URI(host),
                     username,
                     password);
                    restApi.setWsapiVersion(wsapiVersion);
                    restApi.setApplicationName(applicationName);


            JsonObject tcUpdate = new JsonObject();
            tcUpdate.addProperty("Notes", "Fixed3");
            tcUpdate.addProperty("Project", projectRef);
            tcUpdate.addProperty("Test Folder", tfRef);
            UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest("/testcase/186xxx.js", tcUpdate);

            UpdateResponse updateResponse = restApi.update(updateRequest);
            if (updateResponse.wasSuccessful()) {
                System.out.println("Successfully updated test case: ");
            } else {
                            System.out.println("Error");
                        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `TestFolder`, without space:

```
tcUpdate.addProperty("TestFolder", tfRef);
```

You may check [WS API](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) object model to make sure the names of objects are spelled exactly as WS API references them.

There is no need to add .js. WS API v2.0 endpoints do not require .js because that is the only format supported (no more xml).

```
String tfRef = "/testfolder/1234";
```

Note that test folders cannot be moved from one project to another: they belong to the project where they were created. A test case can be moved form one project to another within the same workspace. It means that your project reference should point to the project where the test folder is located. In UI if a test case is in a test folder TF1 inside project P1, and if a user tries to move the test case to another project, P2, this error will come up: `The selected Test Folder is not in the "P2" Project; the Test Folder must be in the same Project as this Test Case or the Parent Project.`